# Moving stored procedure from Firebird to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, firebird

There are databases on Firebird and SQL Server. I have working stored procedure in Firebird.

Question is: how to translate it to T-SQL syntax?

```
begin
  IF ((:PHONE_N is NULL) or (STRLEN(:PHONE_N)<1))  THEN
    BEGIN
      O_PHONE_N = NULL;
      EXIT;
    END

  IF (STRLEN(PHONE_N) > 3) THEN
    BEGIN
      O_PHONE_N = '(' || SUBSTR(:PHONE_N, 1, 3) || ') ';
      PHONE_N = SUBSTR(:PHONE_N, 4, STRLEN(:PHONE_N));
      IF (STRLEN(:PHONE_N)> 3) THEN
        begin
          O_PHONE_N = O_PHONE_N || SUBSTR(:PHONE_N, 1, 3);
          PHONE_N = SUBSTR(:PHONE_N, 4, STRLEN(:PHONE_N));
          IF (STRLEN(:PHONE_NUMBER)> 0) THEN
            O_PHONE_N = O_PHONE_N || '-' ||:PHONE_N;
        END
      ELSE
        O_PHONE_N = :O_PHONE_N || :PHONE_N;
    END
  ELSE
    O_PHONE_N = :PHONE_N;
end
```

Comment: I have some troubles with translating this procedure into T-SQL. It's didn't work... There may be some tables of syntax according?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link might help a bit: http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/migration-mssql-syntax.html

This might help a bit:

- leading `@` marks a T-SQL variable (e.g. `@phone_n`)
- `STRLEN` is called `LEN()` in T-SQL
- `SUBSTR` is `SUBSTRING`

[Check out the excellent MSDN documentation on T-SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189826%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) for more details on T-SQL syntax

Comment: Also: String concatenation is done with `+`, not `||`